# How do I get more CPU seconds allocated in BigQuery when using the java API

Tags: google-bigquery

I get the following error :
`Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Query exceeded resource limits. 6326.429689712539 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 5100.0 CPU seconds.",
    "reason" : "billingTierLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Query exceeded resource limits. 6326.429689712539 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 5100.0 CPU seconds.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}`

when I attempt to run a query in bigquery using the java API. I cannot find how I raise this limit. How do I get more  cpu seconds allocated? How do I change my billing Tier for BigQuery only?

Comment: Rather than trying to change your billing tier, which would incur a much higher cost, you should probably try to optimize your query instead. Sharing the query as part of your question would be a good start.

Comment: I cannot post the query because it is a very long query that involves several temporary functions to mimick postgis from postgres. It joins a 2.7 million row table to a 100k row table in the end. How do I change the billing tier?

Comment: Can you use the native geospatial functionality in BigQuery instead? See [the sign up form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdaf8RsWhQSvC6hnasaRhrtghmiGyDr2z0Vf97w5IDuwUlXdg/viewform).

Comment: I was unaware of a native geospatial bigquery function. Do you know where I can find documentation of such functions?

Comment: Yes, when you sign up, you will receive a copy of the documentation.

Comment: I would still like to know how to change the billing tier if possible. I do not see the option anywhere.

Comment: It's part of the `QueryJobConfiguration`. Did you look there? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/QueryJobConfiguration.java

Comment: I checked this and added this to my job configuration:    
`queryConfig = builder.setMaximumBillingTier(3).build();`   
It did not make a difference. 
I'm not sure how to simply increase the number of CPU seconds I am allowed to use for a query.

Comment: 1 to 100 are treated as the same thing now, so you're going to need to go higher than that. Or use SQL-based functions instead of JavaScript and then this won't be an issue.